# When using external packages in a Java application, do I need to include them entirely in the JAR?

Tags: java, r, intellij-idea, jar, rjava

I am trying to use [Rjava](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html) in my Java application, which requires to have R installed in the computer.

The application works well when being run in the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), but when I pack it in a JAR file and I run it using `java -jar myfile.jar` I get the following error:

```
R_HOME is not set. Please set all required environment variables before running this program.
Unable to start R
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f847c3a470c, pid=4232, tid=4233
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (10.0.2+13) (build 10.0.2+13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (10.0.2+13, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libR.so+0x17270c]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h %e" (or dumping to /home/xvlaze/IdeaProjects/Ypsilon/out/artifacts/Ypsilon/core.4232)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/xvlaze/IdeaProjects/Ypsilon/out/artifacts/Ypsilon/hs_err_pid4232.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Of course, this happens because I did not set up $R_HOME as an environment variable in the IDEA Artifact (and I don't know how to do it, neither). $R_HOME points to `/usr/lib64/R` in my project environment variables, but the JAR can't seem to see it.

Now, the question that comes to my mind is: should I include the content of `/usr/lib64/R` in my JAR in order to make it work or is there another way I don't know?

Comment: What will the result of the command `echo $R_HOME`?

Comment: @AnarAmrastanov Nothing. However, if I run ```R RHOME``` I get ```/usr/lib64/R```.

Comment: I think you should set that env variable. Please, look at  my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should set env variable by command

```
export R_HOME=/usr/lib64/R
```

By this command is session based. So if you want to have that env variable anytime you should set in in your ~/.bashrc file. You should open that file for edit and set to the end of this file the command

```
export R_HOME=/usr/lib64/R
```

For more information about env variables see
https://codeburst.io/linux-environment-variables-53cea0245dc9

Also,
https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables

Comment: Very nice! But what if I need to run the JAR in another machine? Using your answer is a machine-wide solution, but it wouldn't work in, for example, a Windows machine.

Comment: You wrote that error is during packing it into a jar file. So I think if you will set the env variable then you can pack it successfully. If you want to run the jar file on any machine then you have to include required RJava classes into the jar file or transmit required RJava libraries with your jar file.

Comment: Oops, then I did not express myself correctly; the JAR file packs well and your solution solves the problem at a machine level. I already have the required RJava classes inside my JAR file and they work properly. The problem is R does not seem to find ```R_HOME``` inside that JAR and I don't know how to set it up for it to work.

Comment: Do you get that error during the running the jar file?

Comment: Yes, sorry, now I realize I did not clarify at the question. It's edited now!

Comment: I am not sure but seems http://www.rforge.net/rJava/ offers the only installation and you can write an installation for you jar file that will install Rjava to a client machine. Maybe you can use that https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.rosuda.REngine. If you can that you will not have to install something additional on client machine

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. I got my Rjava package from R in my machine itself by opening a terminal, typing ```R``` and running ```install.packages("rJava")```. Then I copied the RJava JARs I got from that installation and added them to my Java project as libraries. Everything works well until I try to run the program in another machine.